# Redirect url is not returning the authorization code when trying to authenticate a power bi web app

Tags: python, azure, python-requests, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I wrote a code using python 3.5.1 to get an authorization code in order to get the access token to be used to access certain Power BI resources.

The web app is registered with Azure AD and I got the client ID and client secret and set up the permissions.

I constructed the query string and passed it to the **get** function of the **requests** library.

```
authstring=https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx&resource=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf

requests.get(authstring)
```

but it keeps redirecting to

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx&resource=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf
```

instead of the redirect url with the code

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf?code=xxXXXXXaaaxaaaxxxxxx....
```

When I put the query string in my browser it redirects and returns the code.

I am not sure what I am missing. Does anyone know how to resolve this or know of a work around?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, you want to do the authentication for integrating Power BI resource with Python, but I don't know your python application is either a client app or a web app.

You can refer to the offical document [Authenticate to Power BI service](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-authenticate-to-power-bi-service/) to know how to do.

According to your description, I think you want to get the access token for requesting the Power BI resource, not access Power BI via single sign on. So you need to do the [`Resource Management Authentication`](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resourcemanagementauthentication.html) using Python SDK with the package [`adal`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python).

Hope it helps.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I am using a web app. I tried it using the Resource Management Authentication and adal but i get a response of 403 when I use ServicePrincipalCredentials to get the token